# Is there a way to split a given month into 4 weeks using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have several functions that split a given month into 4 or 5 weeks. Say I choose August from a ComboBox the code would look something like this, where startWeek and endWeek are automatically prepopulated. Ive started some code below:

**Week1**

```
public function Week1(byVal monthFromComboBox as date)
dim startWeek1 as date,endWeek1 

startWeek1 = "08/01/2019" 'this date should be automatically generated
endWeek1 = "08/03/2019"   'this date should be automatically generated

Week1= Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng, ">=" _ 
startWeek1, _
rng, "<=" & endWeek1) 'week1

Exit Function
End Function
```

**Week 2**

```
public function Week2(byVal monthFromComboBox as date)
dim startWeek2 as date,endWeek2 

startWeek1 = "08/04/2019" 'this date should be automatically generated
endWeek1 = "08/010/2019"  'this date should be automatically generated

Week2= Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rng, ">=" _ 
startWeek2, _
rng, "<=" & endWeek2) 'week2

Exit Function
End Function
```

***and so on........***

End Goal is to create a string from the functions above to plug into a chart for values. The string would read

```
.value = (week1,week2,week3,week4)
```

**Ex: August Split into Weeks**
[image]

*techinically this would be weeks 31 - 35 in 2019*

Comment: Split as in 7 day blocks or as in Mon to Sun? If the latter do pre Monday dates at the start of the month get packaged into the 5th week of the previous month?

Comment: How can a week start on the 1st and end on the 3rd? Perhaps you need to specify how you want the weeks broken down?

Comment: @Enigmativity those dates are week 1 of August

Comment: @dan i would like the weeks of a month spilt up, starting on Monday

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us the end goal here. Why do you need the month divided into weeks exactly?

Comment: @Tom updated my question with my end goal. I would like to create a string from the function values. The string is going to used for chart values

Comment: @Jose - Can you explain what you mean by "week 1 of August"?

Comment: @Enigmativity I edited my question with a calendar screenshot, I've included week labels for weeks 1-4. That is how i would like my code to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For week 1 you can use:

```
startWeek1 = DateSerial(Year(monthFromComboBox), Month(monthFromComboBox), 1)
endWeek1 = DateAdd("d", (7 - Weekday(startWeek1)), startWeek1)
```

For week2,3,4 , you can add the following code after the 2 lines mentioned) where n is the number of week:

```
startWeek2 = DateAdd("d", 1+7*(n-2), endWeek1)
endWeek2 = DateAdd("d", 7*(n-1), endWeek1)
```

Comment: @ctec6, unfortunately, this is throwing a `Runtime 5 , Invalid Call Procedure or Argument`

Comment: there was an error in the DateAdd function... I have corrected it... if it doesn't work tell us in which line is the error happening

Comment: @ctec6 so the first part works fine, the second part is red, not sure where the format is wrong

Comment: I made a small modification in case this is the problem... there was a * missing between the 7 and the (

Comment: @ctec6 brilliant! this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!